# Excluding '__gwt_ObjectId' from JSON.stringify(jso) in DevMode

Tags: gwt

I have a JSON web service, and I've modeled the API as a tree of JavaScriptObject overlay classes. Works great. Except in DevMode where GWT internals and poking through.

It seems in DevMode, for $wnd.JSON.stringify(jso) on EACH object in the tree, there is an additional property added by GWT devmode called '__gwt_ObjectId'. This *shoudln't* be a problem, except the service I'm using seems to be extremely pick so my request is dying with "invalid parameter: __gwt_ObjectId".

In digging through GWT source, I spotted mention of JSON.stringify(jso, replacer), but as the comments said, this isn't available on Safari 4.x. Though though 5 has added it? I'm on Linux but I don't want to start depending on hacks that will screw up others when they try to work on this.

I'd really prefer not to have to munge the result with a regexp after stringifying, as I feel that would probably hurt performance. Same with recursively calling 'delete jso.__gwt_ObjectId' on every object in the tree. :-(

Answer (score 2):

Well, for now this makes things work:

```
return $wnd.JSON.stringify(jso, function(key, value) {
  if (key == '__gwt_ObjectId') {
    return;
  }
  return value;
});
```

(Feel free to respond with this answer if you can provide more details on it's usage and support in browsers.)

Comment: We ran into the same problem (only on Chrome and no Firefox), this solved the problem for us.  Thanks.